# What is the default (blue) value for AppleHighlightColor?

Tags: macos, ui, defaults

Lots of popular dotfiles repos (stemming from [this one](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.osx)) include this:

```
# Set highlight color to green
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleHighlightColor -string "0.764700 0.976500 0.568600"
```

It looks bad. How do I change it back? What was the original value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original value of blue is used when AppleHighlightColor doesn't exist, therefore you can reset it deleting AppleHighlightColor:

```
defaults delete -g AppleHighlightColor
```

You can change the AppleHighlightColor with a GUI through System Preferences → General → Highlight Color.

---

Setting the highlight colour to Green through System Preferences:

```
~ ❯ defaults read -g AppleHighlightColor
0.752941 0.964706 0.678431
```

Setting the highlight colour to Blue  through System Preferences:

```
~ ❯ defaults read -g AppleHighlightColor
2015-05-21 18:47:25.072 defaults[37881:344707] 
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleHighlightColor) does not exist
```

<sup>`-g` is shorthand for NSGlobalDomain</sup>